# acf_register_block_type did not show up in frontpage

Tags: acfpro

I recently created a custom block type with acf like mentioned in the doc, it works just fine in the edit interface in the back-office, but in the front I did not get anything, and when i inspect the html code i get the content commented like this:

```
    <!-- wp:acf/highlighted-posts { "id": "block_5e97574edd1fa", "name": "acf\/highlighted-posts", "data": { "titre": "", "_titre": "field_5e972e607d71e", "read_more": "", "_read_more": "field_5e973516c767d" }, "mode": "preview" } /-->
```

Any ideas please ! ?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is facing this issue: you must use the WordPress Built in function the_content(), otherwise the content will not be parsed correctly. Or you can use the method parse_blocks(), more information’s in the following link : 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/parse_blocks/